# What is the best way to generate HTML using PHP & JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've got a setup of HTML, PHP & jQuery. The steps I want the user to take are as follows:

1. Click a button
2. Modal Appears with dynamic data (taken from button markup, parent div etc.)
3. User Submits Modal & Close

I have two options. To:

1. Generate the HTML prior the user clicking the button. With PHP & Just hide it & then manipulate it with jquery once clicked.
2. Request the the HTML on click via Ajax using an API & again manipulate it with jQuery.

My question is. From the two options which would be the best for performance?

Reading through this and documenting my logic. I'd say that point 1. would be best as I'm not requesting a large amount of data through the API every time?

Can anyone see any advantages to number two? Apart from not requesting the data server side on page load?

Thanks.

Comment: Option two might have an advantage if you have a large amount of modals, but typically only need a small subset (but cannot know which subset). For a single modal, your option1 should typically outperform option two by far (unless the modal is huge and even the single modal is hardly ever needed)

Comment: Point 2 seems to me as two or more data fetch from server. The jQuery manipulation of data doesn't affect on efficiency of responses. I am putting my money on Point 1 as I do the same ;)

Comment: If I only had those two options I would use the first one because it is the easier one. However you should consider using something like Angular.js or React.js so you end up with less of a mess in the end.

Comment: @Burki Yeah, I have this prediciment all the time as i'm developing. Because i have many modals that have different requirements, some dynamic, some static, some with large amounts of data etc. So I get confused every time I come round to choosing point 1 or 2 :) thanks for replying!

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard Hi! Yeah I did my first tutorial on angular the other week. It's fantastic, but I don't really need that kind of js running at the moment! I can definitely see advantages using it though! Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main question here is "how dynamic is the information used to produce that HTML ?".

If there isn't any high probability that the information used to produce that HTML could change at any time, then you should better off with 1st option, since therefore you will be avoiding an additional request to the server.

If the information used to produce that HTML could change at any time, that would be the reason to use the 2nd approach.

Comment: So what i'm basically creating is a share option for items in a feed. Similar to facebook's sharing a post. So the modal stays the same, but the post that is to be shared is the dynamic part of the modal.

Comment: So in this case I think I will use option 1. Generate the modal on page load. Then just get the post data on click and swap the data :)

Comment: Hum, in that case I would suggest maybe this :
1. use jQuery clone() method on the post element to clone the HTML into a container inside the modal.
2. possibly that modal should already be partially created (and hidden as in option #1) so as to have a form to hold any form elements needed to post, like a textarea, etc.